# nginx location regex /yyyy/mm/dd/

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

I'm trying to pass requests from address `example.com/donor/2014/12/07/Name` on the other server.

URIs are like `/donor/2014/12/07/Mike` and I need to convert them to a query type of: `/donor.php?yyyy=2014&mm=12&dd=07&donor=Name`.

My current setup is :

```
location ~* ^/donor/+$ {    
    rewrite ^/(.*) /donor.php?yyyy=$1&mm=$2&dd=$3&donor=$4 break;
    proxy_pass http://X.X.X.X;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to at least learn the basics of regular expression writing and nginx request processing.

This is more appropriate :

```
location /donor/ {    
    rewrite ^/donor/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\w+)$ /donor.php?yyyy=$1&mm=$2&dd=$3&donor=$4? break;
    proxy_pass http://X.X.X.X;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

You'll have to handle `Location` header rewrite with `proxy_redirect` if necessary.